# Passing an Array of Data stored in a variable from Home Component to Another Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array stored in variable called updatedData which i want to move it with the same informations to another functional Component. Can anyone please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with props like so:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.updatedData}</h1>;
}

const updatedData = [];
<Welcome updatedData />
```